# React: multiple selection (through Ctrl or Alt)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't select more than one value. How can I fix it?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: ["grapefruit", "coconut"] };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({ value: [event.target.value] });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert("Your favorite flavor is: " + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select
            multiple={true}
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FlavorForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to get the value of all the currently selected options:

```js
class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { value: ["grapefruit", "coconut"] };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const value = Array.from(event.target.options) // get an array of all options
      .filter(el => el.selected) // remove not selected
      .map(el => el.value); // get the values
    
    this.setState({ value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert("Your favorite flavor is: " + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select
            multiple
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FlavorForm />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `e.target.options` not `e.target.value` then loop through and return/setState with the selected options array:

Using forEach:

```
handleChange (e) {
  const options = e.target.options;
  let value = []
  options.forEach((option)=> option.selected && value.push(option.value))
  this.setState({ value })
}
```

Using reduce:

```
handleChange (e) {
  const value = e.target.options.reduce((selected, option)=> option.selected ? [...selected , option.value] : selected , [])

  this.setState({ value })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to also add a `size` attribute to your `select` element

```
 <select
   multiple={true}
   value={this.state.value}
   onChange={this.handleChange}
   size={4}
 >
```

would allow the user to select up to 4 options